# How to sort and filter all records in AngularJS that are paginated using UI Bootstrap Pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm doing client-side pagination using angular ui-bootstrap [pagination](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination) to add paging to the list and then I'm getting a problem that the sorting and filtering process only sort and filter the data only in the current page.

Here is the code snippets in view to display the data:

```
<tr ng-repeat="reminderType in reminderTypes | filter: paginate | filter: searchText | orderBy:sortBy:sortDescending">
    <td>
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-click="editReminderType(reminderType.ReminderTypeID)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="detailsReminderType(reminderType.ReminderTypeID)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i> View</a>
    </td>
    <td>{{reminderType.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{reminderType.EmailTemplate}}</td>
</tr>
...
<uib-pagination class="pagination-sm"
                        total-items="totalItems" max-size="maxSize" items-per-page="numPerPage" num-pages="numPages"
                        ng-model="currentPage" boundary-links="true" rotate="false"></uib-pagination>
```

and here is the code snippets in controller to do the pagination:

```
$scope.maxSize = 3;
$scope.totalItems = 7;
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.numPerPage = 2;
$scope.paginate = function (value) {
    var begin, end, index;
    begin = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage;
    end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
    index = $scope.reminderTypes.indexOf(value);
    return (begin <= index && index < end);
};
```

I also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198822/angularjs-paging-orderby-only-affects-displayed-page) on SO, but it doesn't work.
How to make this work to sort and filter the data across the page?

I've posted the complete code in [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VwunZUrpyZvNlvcCpAWZ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I'm unable to fork your plunkr, but here is a fix. The JS:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('PagerDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.reminderTypes = [{"ReminderTypeID":1,"Name":"STAMPING OF SPA","EmailTemplate":null},{"ReminderTypeID":2,"Name":"CONDITION PRECEDENT","EmailTemplate":null},{"ReminderTypeID":3,"Name":"STATE AUTHORITY CONSENT","EmailTemplate":null},{"ReminderTypeID":4,"Name":"PAYMENT OF BALANCE PURCHASE PRICE","EmailTemplate":null},{"ReminderTypeID":5,"Name":"CKHT FILING","EmailTemplate":null},{"ReminderTypeID":6,"Name":"TRANSFER FORM 14A","EmailTemplate":null},{"ReminderTypeID":7,"Name":"TRANSFER NOTICE OF ASSESSMENT","EmailTemplate":null}]
  $scope.sortBy = 'Name';
  $scope.sortDescending = false;

  $scope.filteredRT = angular.copy($scope.reminderTypes);

  $scope.searchText = '';

  $scope.maxSize = 3;
  $scope.totalItems = 7;
  $scope.currentPage = 1;
  $scope.numPerPage = 2;
  $scope.paginate = function (value) {
    var begin, end, index;
    begin = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage;
    end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
    index = $scope.filteredRT.indexOf(value);
    return (begin <= index && index < end);
  };

  $scope.filter = function(){
    var results = $scope.filteredRT;
    results.length = 0;
    var searchText = $scope.searchText;
    var reminderTypes = $scope.reminderTypes;

    for(var i = 0; i < reminderTypes.length; ++i){
      if(searchText.length > 0){
        if(reminderTypes[i].Name.includes(searchText)){
          results.push(reminderTypes[i]);
        }
      } else {
        results.push(reminderTypes[i]);
      }
    }
    $scope.totalItems = results.length;

  }
});
```

And the HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="PagerDemoCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-9 col-md-3">
        <p>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Search Text"
                       ng-model="searchText" ng-change="filter()" />
            </div>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr class="bg-info">
                    <th></th>
                    <th>
                        <a ng-click="sortBy = 'Name'; sortDescending = !sortDescending">Reminder Type Name</a>
                        <span ng-show="sortBy == 'Name' && !sortDescending" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                        <span ng-show="sortBy == 'Name' && sortDescending" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a ng-click="sortBy = 'EmailTemplate'; sortDescending = !sortDescending">Email Template</a>
                        <span ng-show="sortBy == 'EmailTemplate' && !sortDescending" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                        <span ng-show="sortBy == 'EmailTemplate' && sortDescending" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="reminderType in filteredRT | filter: paginate | orderBy:sortBy:sortDescending">
                    <td>
                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-click="editReminderType(reminderType.ReminderTypeID)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="detailsReminderType(reminderType.ReminderTypeID)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i> View</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{reminderType.Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{reminderType.EmailTemplate}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="text-right">
                        Showing page {{currentPage}} of {{numPages}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <uib-pagination class="pagination-sm"
                        total-items="totalItems" max-size="maxSize" items-per-page="numPerPage" num-pages="numPages"
                        ng-model="currentPage" boundary-links="true" rotate="false"></uib-pagination>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In particular, I added a ngChange directive in the input filter, and now a copy of reminderTypes is used. Unfortunately, I think that what you aim to do is a bit too complex to work with angular filters alone. I didn't test the order by but the pagination seems to work just fine in this way.

**EDIT** : juste adding the correct fork that respond to the question: https://plnkr.co/edit/HMw8U4OUsW5DNDGfQKHY?p=preview

Comment: as your suggestion `<tr ng-repeat="reminderType in reminderTypes | orderBy:sortBy:sortDescending | filter: searchText | filter: paginate">` but still not working

Comment: Yes, but it still not working. You can check here: https://plnkr.co/edit/2Q9qk4smErwQMc5tyxdn?p=preview

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, you mean that the sort is not correct right ?Are you satisfied with how the text filter behave ?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't sort all of the data only at displayed page and text filter is also not working, when I type 'a' the row is empty

Comment: for the filter, it's because the text filter was not smart, it now put everything to lowercase for filtering https://plnkr.co/edit/HMw8U4OUsW5DNDGfQKHY?p=preview The sort doesn't work yet as expected tough

Comment: Now it should work as expected https://plnkr.co/edit/HMw8U4OUsW5DNDGfQKHY?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately the sorting does not seem to work. it only sorts the first time you click it, then nothing. Debugging it seems that the sort function is called multiple times until it ends up with the same sorting. Cannot seem to find why.

Comment: LOL, just found what was missing in the Plnkr sample. It's missing the "orderBy:sortBy:sortDescription" bit in the ng-repeat. Thanks, my code works perfect now.

Comment: Ok finally sorted the sorting :D. it's always sorting ascending, needed to add condition for when descending is true switch the values. if ($scope.sortDescending){
        nameA = b[sortBy].toUpperCase();
        nameB = a[sortBy].toUpperCase();
      }